# How to implement Push notifications in NET MAUI Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, push-notification, maui

I was wondering if it's there any way to implement push notifications to a desktop maui app. I read a lot of post in forums but all seem to be for android or iOS. Does anyone know if this feature is available for Windows? Thanks for you time.

I expect to be a way to implement windows push notifications using MAUI for a desktop app

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your answer. I saw that post and doesnt seem to be more than an overview, i need a guide or an example to follow if possible.

Comment: Search `Windows Push Notification Services tutorial`? Looks like its designed for use with Azure server. I don't think Firebase supports WIndows Apps (yet?). Not sure if Amazon has a good answer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Json said, you can follow document [Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) overview to learn about this step by step.

You can start with document [Quickstart: Sending a push notification (XAML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/quickstart-send-push-notification).

Your cloud server can send a push notification to your app through the Windows Push Notification Services (WNS). This procedure applies to tile, toast, badge, and raw push notifications.

Parallel to this documentation is documentation on this aspect,you can check it.